# Inicialización del VPTR sin invocar el constructor

Tags: c++

Por ciertos motivos, tengo la necesidad de llamar al *placement new* **sobre una instancia ya correctamente creada**, pero **con su `VPTR` incorrecta**. La he obtenido de un archivo, de un *socket*, ... da igual el método.

Es una clase con funciones-miembro `virtual`, por lo que **necesito** llamar al constructor para inicializar adecuadamente el `VPTR`.

Sin embargo, el constructor **inicializa** todas las variables-miembro. Si fueran *datos primitivos*, no tendría problema. **Pero no lo son**. Algunas de las variables-miembro tienen su propio constructor.

Dándole vueltas, encontré una solución ... ¡ Llamar al *copy constructor* sobre la propia instancia !

```
#include <iostream>

struct Dato {
  int x = 0,
      y = 0;
};

struct Padre {
  Dato datos;

  virtual ~Padre( ) {
  }
};

struct Hija : public Padre {
};

int main( ) {
  Hija h;

  h.datos.x = 10;
  h.datos.y = 20;

  Hija *ptr = new ( &h ) Hija( h );

  std::cout << "x: " << ptr->datos.x << ", y: " << ptr->datos.y << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

<sub>El ejmplo está disponible en [<kbd>Wandbox</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gh9XNmRadeDKv3Ur).</sub>

El resultado obtenido es el buscado:

> x: 10, y: 20

Las preguntas:

1. ¿ Hasta que punto es *portable* esto ?
2. Entiendo que se realiza una llamada recursiva a los distintos constructores implicados. ¿ Hay otro método que ofrezca el mismo resultado (inicializar el `VPTR` **sin** sobrescribir el resto de la memoria), obviando dichas llamadas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿ Hasta que punto es portable esto ?

Si has recuperado un objeto pero la información virtual es incorrecta entiendo que se ha hecho un volcado binario a lo bruto de la memoria del objeto y en consecuencia lo que tienes es, básicamente, basura.

¿Por qué?

El primer motivo es que si se vuelca a lo bruto la memoria de un objeto, si el mismo hace uso de memoria dinámica (da igual que sea el objeto directamente o un objeto interno del mismo), es bastante probable que esa memoria no se esté volcando lo que va a provocar un malfuncionamiento del programa.

Por otro lado, la gestión de la virtualidad queda en manos de los compiladores luego el código fuente de una clase puede generar dos binarios incompatibles al usar compiladores diferentes.

Imagínate el siguiente escenario:

- Compilador A: Almacena toda la información referente a la virtualidad en una región única región de memoria. El acceso a esa memoria se realiza con un puntero que el compilador *inserta* al inicio del objeto.
- Compilador B: Genera una tabla de funciones virtuales y, adicionalmente, gestiona una tabla paralela con información relevante de cara a las conversiones de tipos (`dynamic_cast`). Eso son dos punteros que se *insertan* al inicio del objeto.

En estos contextos los datos que hacen referencia al estado del objeto no están alineados de ninguna manera y cualquier intento de *forzar* que la información relativa a la virtualidad se restaure no va a conseguir arreglar el estado del objeto.

Y no hay que perder de vista que la información binaria es sensible a la arquitectura del equipo: big-endian vs little-endian. Arquitecturas incompatibles frente a los datos binarios.

> Entiendo que se realiza una llamada recursiva a los distintos constructores implicados. ¿ Hay otro método que ofrezca el mismo resultado, obviando dichas llamadas?

La mejor solución pasa por serializar el estado del objeto y enviar y almacenar únicamente dicho estado. Almacenar binariamente un objeto solo puede darte problemas en cuanto se ven involucrados varios equipos con hardware / software diferente.

Soy consciente que serializar los objetos da más trabajo, pero nadie dijo que programar fuese a ser fácil y bonito... bueno, vale, sí, es algo que se vende... pero es mentira!!!

Comment: Como respuesta genérica está muy bien, desde luego :-) Pero tu sabes que todo eso ya lo he tenido en cuenta, y que estoy 100% seguro de que la representación binaria es la misma, y de que mis clases no usan punteros. Puedo *forzar* el VPTR *a lo bestia* yo mismo, pero hacerlo así es poco *portable* (en `gcc` es relativamente fácil). ¿ No se te ocurre ninguna forma *portable* de inicializar el VPTR ?

Comment: Eso lo sabes tu ... hasta que alguien cambia el compilador en alguna máquina y entonces vendrán los problemas: de repente aparecerá memoria dinámica donde antes no la había, cambia la estructura interna del objeto o vete tu a saber qué sucede.

Comment: ¿ *Plan B* entonces ? Ese es todavía mas chulo que el A :-)

Comment: Copiar binariamente objetos es una apuesta arriesgada a medio plazo. Las posibilidades de que el binario pase a ser inservible crece con cada nueva máquina que se incorpore / reemplace en el sistema

Comment: El plan B es serializar los objetos. No se habrían invertido tantos esfuerzos en JSON, ASN.1, google-buffers, etc si no hubiese un motivo por detrás de peso

Comment: Lo se, pero el uso que tiene es concreto. Es un proceso *cache*: por un lado se conecta a la BBDD, manteniendo una copia local de ciertas cosas. Por el otro, se conecta a la GUI. Las clases son compartidas, y se van a ejecutar siempre en la misma máquina. De hecho, la GUI arranca el cache.

Comment: ¡ Pero eso es aburrido, hombre ! xD. El plan B es serializar objetos en formato binario en un bloque de memoria, usando funciones estáticas con un puntero explicito que haga de `this`, usando una clase raiz sin métodos virtuales y sin VPTR. Es básicamente lo mismo, pero complicandolo un poco mas :-)

Comment: Esa caché se puede mantener con serializados de los objetos... eres un tremendista :P

Comment: No, que va. La cache usará SQLite. Se comunicará con el server por HTTP, y con la GUI por el mecanismo este tan chulo que me ha ocurrido después de llevar 4 meses en un proyecto en el que solo resuelvo incidencias sin programar nada de verdad ;-)

Comment: Ahora borramos esto, ¿ Ok ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91586/discussion-between-eferion-and-trauma).

Answer (score 3):

Estoy convencido que tu propuesta deriva en comportamiento indefinido y, en consecuencia, no sería portable. He buscado las citas relevantes de [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)<sup>1</sup> para validar mi argumento (la traducción y el resaltado son míos).

> #### 3.8 Ciclo de vida de objetos.
>
> La vida de un objeto de tipo `T` finaliza cuando:
>
> —(1.3) Si `T` es un objeto con un destructor no trivial. O
>
> —(1.4) **El espacio que el objeto cupa es reutilizado o liberado**.

> 4. Un programa puede finalizar la vida de un objeto al reutilizar el espacio que ocupa dicho objeto o al llamar explícitamente al destructor de un objeto con un destructor no trivial. **Para objetos cuyo tipo tenga un destructor no trivial**, no se requiere que el programa que llame al destructor explícitamente antes de que el espacio que ocupa el objeto sea reutilizado o liberado; sin embargo, **si no hay llamada explícita al destructor o si una *expresión-delete* no es usada para liberar el espacio, el destructor no debe ser llamdao implícitamente y cualquier programa que dependa de los efectos secundarios provocados por el destructor tendrá comportamiento indefinido**.

Respecto al cilo de vida, no pasa nada si se sobrescribe un objeto existente con otro, siempre y cuando el objeto tenga un destructor trivial; en caso contrario el comportamiento es indefinido. ¿Es tu caso?

> #### 12.4 Destructores
>
> **Un destructor es trivial si no está proveído por el usuario** y si:
>
> —(5.4) **el destructor no es virtual**,
>
> —(5.5) **todas las clases base directas de esta clase tienen destructores triviales**, y
>
> —(5.6) para todos los datos miembro no estáticos de la clase que sean de tipo objeto (o formación), cada uno de ellos tenga destructor trivial.
>
> En caso contrario, el destructor no es trivial.

Así que en tu caso, estás forzando un comportamiento indefinido ya que:

1. Finalizas el ciclo de vida de un objeto, al reutilizar su espacio:

   ```
   Hija h; // Inicio del ciclo de vida de h.

   h.datos.x = 10;
   h.datos.y = 20;

   Hija *ptr = new ( &h ) Hija( h ); // Reutilizamos el espacio de h, fin de su vida.
   ```
2. El destructor de `Hija` no es trivial ya que su clase base directa carece de destructor trivial porque además de ser un destructor virtual, es proveído por el usuario.

   ```
   struct Padre {
     Dato datos;

     virtual ~Padre( ) { // Destructor no trivial
     }
   };

   struct Hija : public Padre { // Hereda de Padre
   };
   ```

Al incurrir en comportamiento indefinido, el código podría ser portable, podría no serlo, podría ser ambas cosas a la vez y podría no ser ninguna.

---

1. isocpp.org ha dejado de compartir gratuitamente borradores del estándar C++, el documento enlazado es borrador del estándar de 2014.